# Html5 video command

Tags: html, video, html5-animation

Hallo i would like to make a videocomics for ipad and i tought to create a video in html5 that stops in some timeline point and play again if i press a button. It soulc be possible to do that? thanks a lot.

Comment: So close to being able to edit...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#playing-the-media-resource

Show's you what's possible with the DOM / Javascript :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, do you know please a pratical example where i can learn the effective functions and see the behaviour?

Comment: Here's pretty sweet- http://studio.html5rocks.com/#PiP - have a look round the web, tonnes of demos about :-)

Comment: yes but i didn t find in the web the example i need. someone have found one? thnks